# XMLHttpRequest : calling send() multiple times throws InvalidStateError

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I have the following code:

```
/**
 * Simple method to create a XHR Request
 * @param url
 * @param callback
 * @param method
 * @returns {XMLHttpRequest}
 */
createXhr: function (url, callback, method) {
  if (!method) {
    method = 'GET';
  }

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.addEventListener('load', callback);
  xhr.open(method, url, true);

  if (method === 'POST') {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  }

  return xhr;
}
```

Now I use this code somewhere else as follows:

```
// XHR Requests:
this.accountXhr = utils.createXhr(
  this.account_url,
  this.accountXhrListener.bind(this),
  'POST'
);
```

Now I have a form in my HTML that triggers an XHR request on a change event:

```
checkEmailAddress: function (component, evt) {
  this.accountXhr.send('email=' + encodeURIComponent(evt.target.value));
}
```

Now this code works fine. At least, it works fine the first call. As soon as I change the input-field and the `send()`-method gets triggered again (with different parameters), the console throws the following error:

```
Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
```

Does anyone know what might cause this?

**Edit:** After the comments below, I added a new method to my instantiated XHR object like this:

```
// Add method that opens and send, so we can use the same XHR request to re-send requests:
xhr.openAndSend = function(method, url, data) {
  this.open(method, url);

  if (method === 'POST') {
    this.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  }

  this.send(data);
}.bind(xhr, method, url);
```

Now if I use `openAndSend()` I can - kind of - use `send()` multiple times without having to `open()` it every time. Still, it seems ugly to me. Am I missing something here? Or is this the way to accomplish this?

Comment: the open is only in the createXhr part. can you try puttting the .open in the checkemailaddress?

Comment: But this would mean that I have to re-provide the URL on every request, although the URL never changes? Can't I just call `send()` multiple times while I call `open()` just once?

Comment: i dont think so. have a look at 'XHR lifecycle' [here](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/HTTPClient+and+the+Request+Lifecycle) . but i feel its  ok to hablde. you can either safe the method and url next to accountXhr or maybe even get them from the account XHr itself